# Splitting math sums with python

Tags: python, math

This is a simple question that has been bothering me for a while now.

I am attempting to rewrite my code to be parallel, and in the process I need to split up a sum to be done on multiple nodes and then add those small sums together. The piece that I am working with is this:

```
def pia(n, i):
        k = 0
        lsum = 0
        while k < n:
                p = (n-k)
                ld = (8.0*k+i)
                ln = pow(16.0, p, ld)
                lsum += (ln/ld)
                k += 1
        return lsum
```

where `n` is the limit and `i` is an integer. Does anyone have some hints on how to split this up and get the same result in the end?

Edit: For those asking, I'm not using `pow()` but a custom version to do it efficiently with floating point:

```
def ssp(b, n, m):
    ssp = 1
    while n>0:
            if n % 2 == 1:
                    ssp = (b*ssp) % m
            b = (b**2) % m
            n = n // 2
    return ssp
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do? The only thing that jumps out at me is that you used a `while` loop instead of `for k in xrange(n)`, so you're probably still learning the basics.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't even run. 3-argument `pow` requires integer arguments.

Comment: It isn't worth parallelizing if `n` is not in the range of millions or greater.

Comment: @user2357112 Before Python 2.2 it didn't. This code is either *ancient*, or there is an import of `pow` from somewhere else that's not being shown.

Comment: Also, this is for use of calculating Pi to the millions of digits, to be run on a cluster of Raspberry Pis.

Comment: Your `ssp` function is broken. `ssp(2.25, 3, 1) == 0.015625`, but `2.25**3 % 1 == 0.390625`. There's a reason 3-argument `pow` requires integers.

Comment: There is an excellent article in IEEE spectrum: [The Trouble With Multicore](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-trouble-with-multicore/). In that article the example they use is how to [parallelize the computation of PI](http://spectrum.ieee.org/image/1627665) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the only variable that's used from one pass to the next is `k`, and `k` just increments by one each time, it's easy to split the calculation.

If you also pass `k` into `pia`, then you'll have both a definable starting and ending points, and you can split this up into as many pieces as you want, and at the end, add all the results together.  So something like:

```
# instead of pia(20000, i), use pia(n, i, k) and run
result = pia(20000, i, 10000) + pia(10000, i, 0)
```

Also, since `n` is used to both set the limits and in the calculation directly, these two uses need to be split.

```
from math import pow

def pia(nlimit, ncalc, i, k):
        lsum = 0
        while k < nlimit:
                p = ncalc-k
                ld = 8.0*k+i
                ln = ssp(16., p, ld)
                lsum += ln/ld
                k += 1
        return lsum

if __name__=="__main__":
    i, ncalc = 5, 10
    print pia(10, ncalc, i, 0)
    print pia(5, ncalc, i, 0) + pia(10, ncalc, i, 5)
```

Comment: Implementing it this way produces a problem. Let's say your version is dubbed `spia`. `spia(5,5,0)+spia(10,5,5)` does not equal `spia(10,5,0)`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I found a way. What I did was in the sum I had each node calculate a portion (ex. node one calculates k=1, node 2 k=2, node 3 k=3, node 4 k=4, node 1 k=5...) and then gathered them up and added them.

Comment: what's f=1, f=2, etc?

Comment: f=k, sorry. fixing it.

Comment: OK, but then you're going back and forth for each calculation, and this will be millions of times, and it could take longer than the single processor calculation.  Sorry to plug my own solution here, but with it, you only communicate once per node for the entire calculation.  Anyway, I'll be interested to see whether you really gain something with this approach.